# How can I install WordPress as blog provider , stable?

Tags: multisite, hosting

can I make a Blog Provider like Wordpress.com?

Which features and Plugin exist in wordperss.com but we cant have them in our clone site of WordPress free source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install WordPress as a multisite installation. Check [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)! for how to start. You can google for more tutorials on how to setup a multisite installation.

Comment: install that. but. i cant work with it. for example can i change the default new blog templates? can i have checklist to improve my site and it's usability?